# Which type of model to use and what's my target variable

Tags: dataset, prediction, marketing

I am a beginner in Data Science field, so sorry if my question is too basic.

The task is to build an **ad bidding model for online marketing** which allows you to deliver targeted ads to the right people.
A part of the given data is 
[image: Part of given dataset]

I don't have any additional info about the task. Is my target variable the variable **spent** ?
And if yes which is the best method to follow to predict the target variable?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the variable 'spent' is your target variable. I'd suggest you to analyse the distribution of each feature and target to check if, eventually a linear regression could be appropriate.
You might try different other methods however, like a decision tree regression, which does not require any assumptions as it doesn't estimate parameters.
What I would suggest you to do, howeveer, is to concentrate on the distributions of parameters to check for eventual unbalances and make groups to make estimation robust.

Answer (score 0):

If your model's output is an ad that people might like I would say ad_id is your target variable and you're building a recommendation system. For example, if Person A likes item Ad1, and Person B shows similar feature values (age, gender, etc.), then you could recommend Person B the item Ad1.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what's the question you want to get answered.

The target variable could be `spent` but if you want to optimize what you're spending I think that only make sense when you put it in relation with what you're trying to achieve which I guess are customer conversions.

I would approach this problem in a way that you try to predict what specific ads are bringing more conversions. The ratio between the money `spent` and the `total_conversion` or `approved_conversion` would be your target variable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `spent` is time spent on the page, I'd say that `approved_conversion` is your target variable. Your customer does something (e.g. buy something, register for a newsletter...) on the site (1) or doesn't (0); and one simple classification algorithm to predict that value (0 or 1 with a certain probability) is Logistic Regression. See [ISLR Book Page 131](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Seventh%20Printing.pdf).